# reverse array in javascript from eloquent book

Tags: javascript, arrays, eloquent, reverse

Actually I know there are easier ways to reverse arrays in js, But I need someone's help to understand this reverse method.

Thank you for your help.

```js
function reverseArrayInPlace(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.floor(array.length / 2); i++) {
    console.log(array[array.length - 1 - i])
    let old = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = old;
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(reverseArrayInPlace([1, 2, 3, 4])); // 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Comment: What part of it don't you understand?

Comment: It loops over the array, swapping the Ith element with the Ith-from-last element.

Comment: array[array.length - 1 - i]  this part is for swapping?

Comment: Yes, that's how you get the i'th element from the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has two pointers: one at the start of the array (call this `i`), and one at the end of the array (call this `n - 1 - i`). For each iteration, we swap the values at both pointers. We repeat this until we get to `i = floor(n / 2)`.

By swapping these indices, the array will eventually be reversed. It's easier to see with an example. Suppose you have the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

```
Iteration 1: (i=0, n-1-i=5)
    Pointers at 1 and 6. After swapping, Array=[6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
Iteration 2: (i=1, n-1-i=4)
    Pointers at 2 and 5. After swapping, Array=[6, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1]
Iteration 3: (i=2, n-1-i=3)
    Pointers at 3 and 4. After swapping, Array=[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```